# Fetching YouTube video through API v3

Tags: php, youtube, wamp

I have following code:

```
//$token is an array having parameters: access token, refresh token, token type, expires in and created//

if ($token) {
  $client->setAccessToken($token);
} else {
  $client->refreshToken($token['refresh_token']);
}
// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try {
    // Call the channels.list method to retrieve information about the
    // currently authenticated user's channel.
    $channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', array(
      'mine' => 'true',
    ));

    
    $htmlBody = '';
    foreach ($channelsResponse['items'] as $channel) {
      // Extract the unique playlist ID that identifies the list of videos
      // uploaded to the channel, and then call the playlistItems.list method
      // to retrieve that list.
      $uploadsListId = $channel['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];

      $playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
        'playlistId' => $uploadsListId,
        'maxResults' => 50
      ));

      
        foreach ($playlistItemsResponse['items'] as $playlistItem) 
        {
            
            $videoTitle[$count]=$playlistItem['snippet']['title'];
            $videoDescription[$count]=$playlistItem['snippet']['description'];
            $count++;
        }
    }
  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

}
```

Above code is used to fetch videos from various YouTube accounts. I am getting an issue that: At beginning I initialize the `$token` for account A and videos are fetched from account A but after that next time when I initialize the `$token` for account B, I am still getting the videos for account A.

I am frustrated with this problem. `$token` is showing me correct value at run time.